# Limiting permission on all items and views

Tags: list, list-view, custom-list

SP 2013

I have a list called Processes, which has the usual All Items view and another view called Process Holders (this has less fields than the All Items view).

There are about 15 users who have permissions to the list.

I need to restrict the All Items view to 10 people and let all 15 people see the Process Holders view

Is there anything I can do to implement this. Is it possible to create another field on the list and add a share point group to that field and put a filter on to restrict the list to that group on All Items?

Are there any other workarounds as the list has been put of of use for now till this is solved?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one option to set the permissions on view called "Target Audience".

To set the target audience, you need to edit the page, then edit the list web part you want to assign the permissions.

In web part properties, you will get the option to set the target audience for that particular web part(Under "Advanced" option).

Please accept this as answer, if this answered your question.

Comment: Here is a link with more info if they need it. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Target-content-to-specific-audiences-33D84CB6-14ED-4E53-A426-74C38EA32293