# Share my personal view on SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view

I am fairly new to SharePoint. When I create a new view, I am only able to create public or personal.

I would like to create a view that can have multiple people but not everyone. It would also work if I could just share my personal view.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using? Are you using classic experience or modern experience?

Comment: I believe I have access to both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For classic experience**:

There is one option to set the permissions on view called "Target Audience".

Check my full answer given at: [Limiting permission on all items and views](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/250560/limiting-permission-on-all-items-and-views/250570#250570)

**Microsoft documentation**: [Target navigation, news, and files to specific audiences](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/target-navigation-news-and-files-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293?#ID0EABAAA=Office_2010_-_2019)

---

**Form modern experience**:

Currently there is no way to use target Audience in SharePoint Modern List view.

However, you can try the workaround given in my answer at: [limit a user to see specific view of a SharePoint list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/277474/limit-a-user-to-see-specific-view-of-a-sharepoint-list/277477#277477)

Comment: Thank you! I am following from modern experience and I am lost on step 4. I do not have anything that says "edit webpart" I only have something that says "add webpart"

Comment: Did you see the list web part added on classic experience page in editing mode? You need to select the web part & then you have option to edit the web part from 2 places. one is from top ribbon on page & 2nd at right most top corner of web part, there is small dropdown type icon --> clicking on it will show some options related to web part.

Comment: I think I understand now! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: How do I make a group? The internet is saying to go to site settings, but I do not have any tab that says site settings @Ganesh Sanap